# Cool question in linear algebra about dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite vector space and U W, Z are sub-spaces of V.
dimZ =dim(U+W), dimW = dim(Z+U), dimU = dim(W + Z). Show that U=Z=W.

I subtracted between the equations and got here:
I used the formula $dim(X+Y) = dim(X) + dim(Y) -dim(X \cap Y)$

$dim (U \cap W) + dim (U \cap Z) + dim (Z \cap W) = dim(U)+dim(W)+dim(Z)$

how do I continue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to assume that the proposition is false and see what happens.

Suppose $U \ne W.$ Then $ dim(U \cap W) < dim(U)$. Plugging this into your equation,
$$
dim(U\cap Z)+dim(Z\cap W)-dim(W)-dim(Z)> 0.
$$
But we know that $dim(Z\cap W)-dim(W) \le 0$ and $dim(U\cap Z)-dim(Z) \le 0.$ This contradicts the equation you wrote, thus $U= W.$  The same argument works to prove that $U = Z.$  Then, by the transitive property, $U=W=Z.$

Comment: Well done sir! I really liked what you did there